# Force Container Height via css (using Avada with Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, containers, height

Outside of Fusion Builder Elements' margin, padding and separators, is there a way in purely css to force a Container's height with Avada?

I was told I have to target the Container, Column and wrapper. Trying to.  I would think it would be something like, add class to Container and inner Column, then add to css:

```css
    .fusion-fullwidth .fullwidth-box .my-class,
    .fusion_builder_column .my-class {
        height: 600px !important!;
    }
```

I get it that we can pad the contents in the Builder, but I'd rather use css because that's where I like my control to be. If possible.

I don't know if you need a demo page, or if seasoned Avada users will be answering. If you need a page I can put it in the comments.

Comment: Can you give the link of that page where you have added that custom class?

Comment: .fusion-fullwidth.fullwidth-box.my-class.nonhundred-percent-fullwidth.non-hundred-percent-height-scrolling {
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: This might help ?

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: Demo page deleted. Issue solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

My coder friend figured it out. The answer is:

```
.my-class .fusion-layout-column .fusion-column-wrapper {
    min-height: 1px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

:p